# Azure AD device flow verification_url

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Consider this Azure AD OAuth 2.0 device flow grant request:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/devicecode
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
&grant_type=device_code
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

(skipped urlencoding for readability)

According to [**this draft**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-07), response should include a `verification_uri` parameter:

> `verification_uri`

> REQUIRED.  The end-user verification URI on the authorization server.  The URI should be short and easy to remember as end-users will be asked to manually type it into their user-agent.

> ```
> {
> ```

```
   "device_code": "GMMhmHCXhWEzkobqIHGG_EnNYYsAkukHspeYUk9E8",
   "user_code": "WDJB-MJHT",
   "verification_uri": "https://www.example.com/device",
   ...
```

However the response from Azure AD contains
`verification_url` instead (note `url` instead of `uri`):

```
"verification_url": "https://aka.ms/devicelogin"
```

**Is this just a typo in Azure AD's Device Flow implementation?
Should i take both variants as valid? Is this being renamed to `verification_url` in the next draft?**

One additional question, **can i request device flow grant from an Azure AD *v2* endpoint?**

The token endpoint seems to exist as `/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`, but its code request counterpart returns `404`, `/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode`.

There is a `/common/oauth2/devicecode`, but i'm unable to use it later with `/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode` (immediately returns *AADSTS70019 Verification code expired.*).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a typo. The IETF draft (that you referred to) is backed by both Google and Microsoft. But both companies implemented it without regard to this difference, namely "verification_uri" vs. "verification_url".

Google came first. They implemented the device flow years ago. I'm not sure of the exact date of first publication, but it was already available in 2012. And they used "verification_url" from the start! The IETF draft's first version dates back to 2015 and for some reason the Google team responsible for the draft made the decision to use "verification_uri" despite the fact that their own implementation already used "verification_url" for years. And they never changed neither the draft, nor their implementation. They use "verification_url" in their documentation as well.

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices

Facebook on the other hand uses the draft's version for the field name, i.e. "verification_uri". Check out their documentation (and the implementation is aligned with the doc): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices

I've yet to find an official documentation for Microsoft's (i.e. Azure's) device flow implementation, but here're the few posts/articles that are about this subject and are on a *.microsoft.com domain:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/02/13/assisted-login-using-the-oauth-deviceprofile-flow/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile/

The latter is accompanied by a GitHub repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile

And here're a few non-MS sources:

- https://www.jkawamoto.info/blogs/device-authorization-for-azure/
- https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/03/12/azure-ad-device-profile-oauth-flow/

Actually the latter one (it's in Japanese) is the first detailed example of Azure's device flow implementation that I could find. :-) And it has "verification_url" as well.

As for your "additional question" ("can i request device flow grant from an Azure AD v2 endpoint?"), I've no idea. Microsoft's device flow implementation is not even official(ly supported yet, at least the lack of documentation suggests this), so it's subject to change.

The v2.0 protocol pages do not mention the "devicecode" endpoint either.
See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare

So for now I suggest not to build anything production-like on Azure's device flow.